# React-Router v4 - why does my app reload if I manually change the url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I manually changed the URL in the address bar and the page reloads,

I thought it would just render the correct route. How come it reloads?

Is this normal?

Comment: how do you "manually" change the URL? show the code.

Comment: Just edit the address bar!